# ASCIIMathMl in ipython notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Since ipython notebook renders math using the mathjax library. Mathjax officially supports the asciimath syntax. But I'm unable to get it rendered correctly in ipython notebook

```
from IPython.display import Math
Math(r'x^2 or a_(m n) or a_{m n} or (x+1)/y or sqrtx')
```

the syntax inside the quotes is [asciimath](http://www1.chapman.edu/~jipsen/mathml/asciimathsyntax.html) syntax. IPython notebook 1.0 dev cannot render it correctly. Is there a way to enable this support.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it but this link is supposed to show how to enable asciimath in an [ipython notebook](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/4052).

One of the developers explains why they prefer to use LaTeX.

Comment: The link explains why they won't add ASCIIMath support to iPython notebook. The issue was closed without further discussion.